# flattening joins in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

If I wanted to JOIN two tables I could do this:

```
$books = App\Book::with('author')->get();
```

The problem with that is that the results are kinda nested. eg. If I wanted to get the DOB of the author I'd have to do this:

```
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->author->dob;
}
```

But what if I, instead, wanted to be able to do this?:

```
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->dob;
}
```

How might I go about doing that? I suppose there could be a conflict dob was a column in the `book` table and the `author` table and that doing `author_dob` would be better but let's assume there isn't a conflict.

I guess a view could do the trick but is there a way to do that in Laravel without having to create a view?

Comment: `App\Book::with('author')` is not joining but eager loading, it's actually two queries

Comment: Have a look: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#joins

Answer (score 2):

```
$books = DB::table('books')
            ->join('authors', 'authors.id', '=', 'books.author_id')->get()
```

Actually you can do the same using eloquent. This way, you'll  have access to all functions and extra parameters in your Book model file

```
App\Book::join('authors', 'authors.id', '=', 'books.author_id')->get()
```

You might want to use `leftJoin()` instead of `join()`